# npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin when trying to run "npm run start"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, npm

after I installed MongoDB, I've got an error as shows below:

```
$ npm run dev

> server-semina-bootcamp@0.0.0 dev
> nodemon ./bin/www

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin
npm ERR! path D:\programming\Javascript\Program-NodeJS\website-event
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell_\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-31T04_06_41_564Z-debug-0.log
```

I have already tried uninstalling MongoDB and NodeJS and reinstalling it.
and I've already check MongoDb path in environment variables But the error still showing, is there any solution to this error?

Here's the complete LOG file:

```
0 verbose cli C:\NodeJs\node.exe C:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.6.7
2 info using node@v18.17.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:D:\programming\Javascript\Program-NodeJS\website-event\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\dell_\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\dell_\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 9ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm run dev
21 verbose argv "run" "dev"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\dell_\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-31T04_06_41_564Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\dell_\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-31T04_06_41_564Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 23ms
31 timing command:run Completed in 9ms
32 verbose stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin ENOENT
32 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
32 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
32 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
33 verbose pkgid server-semina-bootcamp@0.0.0
34 verbose cwd D:\programming\Javascript\Program-NodeJS\website-event
35 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
36 verbose node v18.17.0
37 verbose npm  v9.6.7
38 error code ENOENT
39 error syscall spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin
40 error path D:\programming\Javascript\Program-NodeJS\website-event
41 error errno -4058
42 error enoent spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin ENOENT
43 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
43 error enoent
44 verbose exit -4058
45 timing npm Completed in 53ms
46 verbose code -4058
47 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell_\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-31T04_06_41_564Z-debug-0.log
```

and here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "server-semina-bootcamp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```